# Is there any way to create something like Web-to-lead for custom object

Tags: apex, api, web2lead

can anybody tell me if it is possible to create something like Web-to-lead(Integrate online forms with Salesforce) for custom objects.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two approaches, both involving visualforce pages and sites: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites

First is to embed a visual workflow screen in a visualforce page, then expose the VF page via sites. The VF page is just a container and the flow has the fields and logic within in it. The VF page could be as simple as:

```
<apex:page>
    <flow:interview name="[name of flow here]" buttonLocation="bottom" finishLocation="[returnURL here]">
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

More information on flow here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_admin_flow_overview.htm&language=en_US

The second option is to build all your own logic and custom VF page but still host it via a force.com site. The link below provides an example based upon using the Case object but should give you the basis to build your own from:
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Custom_Web-To-Case_Forms_Using_Visualforce_and_Sites

Comment: Girbot, thank you for taking the time to reply with these approaches. I am gonna go ahead and try  the second option. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

Girbot gave the correct answer for developers. If you (or others) aren't developers, then there are even easier solutions - use one of the many form tools available on the AppExchange. You can pick between FormAssembly, FormStack, FormWhatever... I forget all their names.

You will end up paying some USD $40 a month but this is a flat per-org (not per-user or per-form) price, so very reasonable. And some of them will do multi-page forms, or single-form to multiple custom objects, embedded iframes on your site, and other nifty features. Each tool has it's own strengths and weaknesses, so figure out the features you need and find the one that fits best.

Their feature sets are so different that some companies end up using two different form tools.

best of luck
stony

Comment: FWIW I have found FormAssembly to be excellent in connecting with Salesforce objects (Standard and Custom).  I've used the enterprise version many times to automate company processes that used to be very manual (sending a spreadsheet via email and then manually inputting the returned data).  It's super easy to embed IDs and other information so that you can send users a form that will automatically update Salesforce after they submit it (create new records or update current records).

Comment: Yes, following on McD, that's one of FormAssembly's strengths. People want to build out crazy password/login/force.com pages, and find they can accomplish 98% of the same thing by emailing someone a FormAssembly link with fields prepopulated in the URL and even the record itself reference in the URL. Good point, McD!

Answer (score 1):

The one solution we have come up with is using Zapier as a middle man solution. Honestly it works a treat. If you're using Wordpress for your forms this is even easier. Link is here if you want to take a look.

http://moometric.com/integrations/sf/wordpress-form-submissions-salesforce-custom-object/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative *could* be to write code that then creates records of the custom object(s) that you want using the data from the leads created via the web-to-lead form. Afterwards, the logic could delete the lead record as it may no longer be required.

It's not the most elegant solution but could be a cost/time saver for a minimum viable product. I would agree that the ideal solution currently would be to rely on a third party app like [FormAssembly](https://www.formassembly.com/salesforce/) or [Clicktools](https://www.sap.com/products/acquired-brands/what-is-calliduscloud-clicktools.html).